# Question about Obi Wan and Dooku in Attack of the Clones

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones

I just saw Episode II and loved it but I’m curious about one thing. I might be looking into it too much but here goes:

A lot of synopses about the movie's plot, including on the Wikipedia page, talk about Obi Wan learning “the truth” about the Seperatist movement/Sith plot on Geonosis. I’m assuming the truth that he learns is that:

1. Dooku is the leader of the seperatist movement
2. Dooku and Nute Gunray were the ones who authorized the assassination attempts against Padme
3. The seperatist movement is building an army of battle droids
4. Much of the republic senate is under the control of a Sith Lord…

And that’s it right?

Or was there something else he learned? Was “Obi Wan learns the truth” referring to anything else?

Answer (score 7):

It was Dooku's way of tempting Obi-Wan and making him, already not a fan of politicians, give up on the Republic and join his movement.

> Count Dooku: It's a great pity that our paths have never crossed before, Obi-Wan. Qui-Gon always spoke very highly of you. I wish he were still alive. I could use his help right now.
>
> Obi-Wan: Qui-Gon Jinn would never join you.
>
> Count Dooku: Don't be so sure, my young Jedi. You forget that he was once my apprentice, just as you were once his. He knew all about the corruptions of the Senate, but he would never have gone along with it if he had learned **the truth** as I have.
>
> Obi-Wan: The truth?
>
> Count Dooku: The truth. What if I told you that the Republic was now under the control of a Dark Lord of the Sith?
>
> Obi-Wan: No, that's not possible. The Jedi would be aware of it
>
> Count Dooku: The Dark Side of the Force has clouded their vision, my friend. Hundreds of senators are now under the influence of a Sith Lord called Darth Sidious.
>
> Obi-Wan: I don't believe you.
>
> Count Dooku: You must join me, Obi-Wan, and together we will destroy the Sith!
>
> Obi-Wan: I will never join you, Dooku.

But the real issue that he didn't fully reveal *the truth*, he didn't tell him who Sidious really was, he just says that he is **influencing senators** not being the supreme Chancellor himself, it was as Yoda said later a deceitful way of creating mistrust.

> Master Yoda: Joined the Dark Side, Dooku has. Lies, deceit, creating mistrust are his ways now.